# Как правильно сделать рефакторинг?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть код, который устанавливает шрифт для вью элементов.
Я создал класс `Utils` в который выношу все вот такие инструментальные функции.

Вот функция

```
/**
 * Set the font to TextView
 **/
private void fontInit() {
    TextView tvWelcomeAct1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct1);
    TextView tvWelcomeAct2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct2);
    TextView tvWelcomeAct3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct3);
    TextView tvWelcomeAct4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct4);
    TextView tvWelcomeAct6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct6);
    TextView tvWelcomeAct7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomAct7);

    List<TextView> fontList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(fontList, tvWelcomeAct1, tvWelcomeAct2, tvWelcomeAct3,
            tvWelcomeAct4, tvWelcomeAct6, tvWelcomeAct7);

    for (int i = 0; i < fontList.size(); i++) {
        UtilClass.setFont(context, fontList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Меня начало смущать то, что она у меня дублируется эта функция во всех `Activity`...

В идеале я б хотел оптимизировать эту функцию так, чтоб она принимала `context` и через запятую все вью, вне зависимости от их количества...

что то вроде такого

```
private void fontInit(context, tvWelcomeAct1, tvWelcomeAct2, tvWelcomeAct3, tvWelcomeAct4, tvWelcomeAct6, tvWelcomeAct7) {
    List<TextView> fontList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(fontList, **только как их сюда передать**);

    for (int i = 0; i < fontList.size(); i++) {
        UtilClass.setFont(context, fontList.get(i));
    }
```

Спасибо за совет)

Comment: На сколько я понял из описания, Вам поможет метод с аргументами переменной длинны (varargs) http://www.linkex.ru/java/varargs.php

P.S. На сколько я помню такие вещи лучше делать через стили, или Вы в рантайме меняете?

Comment: Да нет... Мне нужно просто использовать свой шрифт... Не обязательно в рантайме. А как через стиль задать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы постоянно везде во все `TextView` пихаете свой шрифт, то по чему бы не сделать это постоянным атрибутом у самого `TextView`?
Самый простой вариант
Создайте новый класс и унаследуйте его от `TextView`

```
public class ExTextView extends TextView {

    public ExTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public ExTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        parseAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    private void parseAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExTextView);
        int typeface = values.getInt(R.styleable.ExTextView_typeface, 0);
        setTypeface(FontsUtils.getTypeFace(context, typeface));
        values.recycle();
    }

}
```

Создайте файл `attrs.xml` в `values` или дополните его если уже имеется

```
<declare-styleable name="ExTextView">
        <attr name="typeface" />
    </declare-styleable>

<attr name="typeface" format="enum">
        <enum name="FONTS1" value="0" />
        <enum name="FONTS2" value="1" />
        <enum name="FONTS3" value="2" />
    </attr>
```

Ну и класс для загрузки самого шрифта

```
public class FontsUtils {
    public final static int FONTS1 = 0;
    public final static int FONTS2 = 1;
    public final static int FONTS3 = 2;

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, int typeFace) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            String assetPath;
            switch (typeFace) {
                case FONTS1:
                default:
                    assetPath = "fonts/FONTS1.otf";
                    break;
                case FONTS2:
                    assetPath = "fonts/FONTS2.otf";
                    break;
                case FONTS3:
                    assetPath = "fonts/FONTS3.otf";
                    break;
            }
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    cache.put(assetPath, Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), assetPath));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TypeFaces", "Typeface not loaded.");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, как все это работает

Во все ваши `xml` с `TextView`, где нужно менять фон меняем их на наш кастомный, где `you.package.name.` вы должны заменить на имя пакета вашего приложения.

```
<you.package.name.ExTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

Если вы явно не указали какой шрифт использовать, будет использоваться шрифт по умолчанию в ветки `default` (смотрите класс `FontsUtils`).

Если нужно указать шрифт используйте префикс `app:typface` (не забудьте добавить `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` в рут лайоут)

```
<you.package.name.ExTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:typeface="FONTS2"
                />
```

Если по каким то причинам требуется добавить шрифт программно:

```
TextView.setTypeFace(FontsUtils.getTypeFace(mContext, FontsUtils.FONTS2));
```

Будут вопросы задавайте =)
Таким не хитрым способом вы будете себе экономить при добавлении новых  `TextView`, так как по умолчанию будет использоваться указанный вам шрифт (в примере это `FONTS1`).

Comment: Да, но задача усложняется тем, что я изменяю шрифт, не только у `TextView`, а и у других вью тоже... Тогда прийдется для каждой вью создать такой класс... А так у меня просто метод в инструментальном классе, в который я передаю любые вью в любом количестве и не заморачиваюсь с содержанием кастомных классов... Но за ответ спасибо! Очень подробно. Сохраню себе на потом))

Comment: Чтобы не изменять шрифт у других просто используйте обычный TextView =) или измените код, так чтобы по дефолту ничего не происходило =)

Comment: Да, но задача усложняется тем, что я изменяю шрифт, не только у TextView, а и у других вью тоже... Вот тут вас не понял, про какой вы кейс , а и у других вью тоже... ....

Comment: Данный код после добавления явно не меняет сразу у всех шрифт ) Данный код будет работать только для той вью, которой вы указали. Вы на экран можете добавить 5  TextView и 3 ExTextView, в таком случае нестандартный шрифт будет именно у 3х ExTextView, другие View это не коснется.

Comment: Хотя я только, что подумал, что наверное это будет удобно все таки)) У меня на самом деле не так много вью элементов... Но тогда как быть с `EditText` и `Button`? Нужно создать для них отдельно классы, верно?

Comment: А что вы думаете о использовании либов `MagicViews и Calligraphy` как советовал @xkor ?

Comment: Да все верно, создать ExButton и наследоваться от Button... и так далее.. для все отслаьных View где нужно менять шрифт

Comment: Там более развита тема изменения шрифтов =) я ими не пользовался, (даже не знал о существования до тог опока не прочитал все ответы =)) но Суть одинаковая, вам нужно будет будет использовать View из их библиотек, чтобы быстро менять шрифт. Мне достаточно того что я привел вам в коде. сам пользуюсь.

Comment: ок спасибо...))

Answer (score 4):

Используем `varargs` и цикл `foreach`:

```
void fontInit(Context context, TextView ... fontList ) {
    for (TextView textView : fontlist) 
        UtilClass.setFont(context, textView);
}
```

Вызываем метод, перечисляя сколько нужно `TextView` после `context`:

```
fontInit(context, tvWelcomeAct1, tvWelcomeAct2, tvWelcomeAct3);
```

Answer (score 3):

То что вы хотите будет выглядеть как то так:

```
private void fontInit(Context context, TextView... textViews) {
    for (TextView textView : textViews) {
        UtilClass.setFont(context, textView);
    }
}
```

Но конкретно в случае с кастомными шрифтами я бы вам рекомендовал не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться одним из уже готовых решений. [Вот целая категория библиотек](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/37?sort=rating) позволяющих так или иначе использовать кастомные шрифты. Из наиболее простых и удобных я бы выделил [MagicViews](https://github.com/ikocijan/MagicViews) и [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy).